configuring CloudFront caching based on origin response headers
I'm currently working on configuring caching behavior in Amazon CloudFront, I want to control wether CloudFront cache content or not  based on the presence or absence of certain headers in the origin response.
Goal:
origin response with  some-custom-headr=true will be cached by CloudFront.
origin response with  some-custom-headr=false or non existing  some-custom-headr won't  be cached by CloudFront.
